# Why isn't my for-loop executing?

Tags: java, android

In my try block i have a for loop which I'm certain isn't working as when I log in the for loop I get nothing back meaning in my application the loop isn't being accessed.

Here is my try block which includes the for loop:

```
try 
        {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
            {
                anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                String line = new String();
                while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                {

                    result = result + line;
                }
            }

                    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    Log.v(TAG, "index1=" + menuItems);

                    Handler parser = new Handler();
                    String xml = result; // getting XML
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                    Log.v(TAG, "index2=" + nl);

                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG, "index3=" + nl);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                        map.put(KEY_AVERAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                        map.put(KEY_LOWEST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                        map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
                        Log.v(TAG, "index4=" + map);

                        menuItems.add(map);
                        Log.v(TAG, "index5=" + menuItems);
                    }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            try 
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        return menuItems;
```

i added the catch and return for completeness incase perhaps these are the cause. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's nothing to iterate over.

Comment: make sure you aren't getting the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Dave sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: Does anyplace inside of your try block LOG ? Or does your catch block LOG instead ?

Comment: are you calling the HTTP code from onCreate() or a different method that has been written in your activity..

Comment: user2450263 this is all done within an asyncTask inner class. On the doInBackground method so its on a different method. Also its within the method its used in. Before the try catch block

Comment: okay, just mentioned that to make sure it wasn't the case, most of the times it is

Comment: jesse no im unable to log into catch

Comment: codeMagic adding that breaks the loop. i get an error

Comment: As a side issue, a try-catch like that is only going swallow the actual exception and print the stacktrace for a new exception that does not know anything about the root cause of your issue. In the future you might consider the IOException constructor that takes a Throwable as the cause and incorporates it into the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether your NodeList is empty? If your getElementsByTagName call returns an empty list, then the length of it will be 0, and your for loop will be skipped because the termination condition will be met before the first iteration. Try logging the length of nl.